# sql server multiple left outer joins linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server

э  Here is an sql query :)

```
DECLARE @uDomain nvarchar(255)
SET @uDomain = 'loadtest'
INSERT INTO newnd.dbo.new_attributes
SELECT u.vdsUserId, u.vdsDomain, 
    a1.vdsValue,
    a2.vdsValue
    a3.vdsValue,
    a4.vdsValue,
    a5.vdsValue,
    a6.vdsValue,
    a7.vdsValue,
    a8.vdsValue,
    a9.vdsValue,
    a10.vdsValue,
    a11.vdsValue
    a12.vdsValue
    a13.vdsValue
    a14.vdsValue
    FROM ([linkedserver].master.dbo.vdsUser u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver].master.dbo.vdsUserAttr a1 ON a1.vdsUserId = u.vdsUserId AND a1.vdsDomain = u.vdsDomain AND a1.vdsName = 'as1'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver].master.dbo.vdsUserAttr a2 ON a2.vdsUserId = u.vdsUserId AND a2.vdsDomain = u.vdsDomain AND a2.vdsName = 'as2'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver].master.dbo.vdsUserAttr a3 ON a3.vdsUserId = u.vdsUserId AND a3.vdsDomain = u.vdsDomain AND a3.vdsName = 'as3'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver].master.dbo.vdsUserAttr a4 ON a4.vdsUserId = u.vdsUserId AND a4.vdsDomain = u.vdsDomain AND a4.vdsName = 'as4'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver].master.dbo.vdsUserAttr a5 ON a5.vdsUserId = u.vdsUserId AND a5.vdsDomain = u.vdsDomain AND a5.vdsName = 'as5'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver].master.dbo.vdsUserAttr a6 ON a6.vdsUserId = u.vdsUserId AND a6.vdsDomain = u.vdsDomain AND a6.vdsName = 'as6'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver].master.dbo.vdsUserAttr a7 ON a7.vdsUserId = u.vdsUserId AND a7.vdsDomain = u.vdsDomain AND a7.vdsName = 'as7'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver].master.dbo.vdsUserAttr a8 ON a8.vdsUserId = u.vdsUserId AND a8.vdsDomain = u.vdsDomain AND a8.vdsName = 'as8'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver].master.dbo.vdsUserAttr a9 ON a9.vdsUserId = u.vdsUserId AND a9.vdsDomain = u.vdsDomain AND a9.vdsName = 'as9'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver].master.dbo.vdsUserAttr a10 ON a10.vdsUserId = u.vdsUserId AND a10.vdsDomain = u.vdsDomain AND a10.vdsName = 'as10'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver].master.dbo.vdsUserAttr a11 ON a11.vdsUserId = u.vdsUserId AND a11.vdsDomain = u.vdsDomain AND a11.vdsName = 'as11'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver].master.dbo.vdsUserAttr a12 ON a12.vdsUserId = u.vdsUserId AND a12.vdsDomain = u.vdsDomain AND a12.vdsName = 'as12'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver].master.dbo.vdsUserAttr a13 ON a13.vdsUserId = u.vdsUserId AND a13.vdsDomain = u.vdsDomain AND a13.vdsName = 'as13'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkedserver].master.dbo.vdsUserAttr a14 ON a14.vdsUserId = u.vdsUserId AND a14.vdsDomain = u.vdsDomain AND a14.vdsName = 'as14'
) WHERE u.vdsDomain = @uDomain
```

This is an sql query to somehow convert table like (..., key, ..., value, ...) to (a1, a2, a3, a4, ..., a14) for each of 14 possible keys and some other restrictions. However, each using of construction like "a1.vdsValue" or "u.vdsDomain" leads to error:

```
The multi-part identifier "u.vdsDomain" could not be bound
```

What may be the problem here?

Comment: a `'` is missing at the end of the line of your first left join

Comment: This should fail for multiple reasons. First of all, as the comment before says, you are missing a `'` on your first join. You also didn't give an alias to the whole `FROM ........) WHERE ...`, you either gave it an alias or better yet, remove the parentheses

Comment: Sorry, that's my error while copy-pasting-editing. This query works fine on our test environment, but failes on the customer machine. May this problem be with different SQL Server versions?

Comment: Just get rid of those parenthesis around your joins. They are the problem and provide nothing but noise in this query.

Comment: @goldaniga you are the only one that can tell if the problem is the version because there is no mention of the involved server versions in the question. does the server have different versions? which versions?

Comment: @goldaniga your query, as written, shouldn't run in SQL Server

Comment: It runs perfectly on our test environment :)